# Knowing iOS Private Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks

There are so many private frameworks in iOS.
However, it is not easy to know what purpose of a certain framework is even if I have its header files. (For example, I don't know what AirTraffic.framework, CellularPlanManager.framework is and how to use it.)
Is there any summary about it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html

Answer (score 0):

Apple don't have a documentation for Private Frameworks and APIs available for Public. But still you can search for particular framework.
Here's a list of private Frameworks.

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

Using Private Frameworks lead to rejection of App to App Store. So its better to avoid using Private APIs.